# SQL Database - Update Record via PHP Form. No Errors, but no update.

Tags: php, sql, forms, phpmyadmin

Hoping this is the right area to be putting this. At current I'm working on a little project for fun and at the same time attempting to teach myself some PHP. I've created a little 'Audit' page that's associated with my website that allows me to Input new data to a pre-existing SQL Database, Search on that Data and Update that Data. Now, the Adding and Search works without a Hitch. The only problem is the 'Update' function does not... It does not Error (in fact it states it is successful) and it all works how it should, except that it does not 'actually' update the information within the table.

I've spent the past 2-3 days reading through StackOverflow, Tutorial Guides, Forums and just playing with parts of the code myself, none of which has provided even a 'remote' answer.

I have 2 pages that are relevant, the 'update.php' page and the 'update_ac.php' page that runs the script after hitting 'submit' on the Form, the code is as below:

update.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="member2"; // Mysql username 
$password="********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="audits"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="data"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Barcode</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Product</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Category</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Assigned</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Notes</strong></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="barcode" type="text" id="barcode" value="<? echo $rows['barcode']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="product" type="text" id="product" value="<? echo $rows['product']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td align="center">
<select name="category" id="category" value="<? echo $rows['category']; ?>">
<option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
<option value="Software">Software</option>
<option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
</select>
</td>  
<td align="center">
<select name="assigned" id="assigned" value="<? echo $rows['assigned']; ?>">
<option value="name1">Name 1</option>
<option value="name1">Name 2</option>
<option value="name1">Name 3</option>
<option value="name1">Name 4</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="notes" type="text" id="notes" value="<? echo $rows['notes']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

update_ac.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="member2"; // Mysql username 
$password="********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="audits"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="data"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET barcode='$barcode', product='$product', category='$category', assigned='$assigned', notes='$notes' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='assets.php'>View Changes</a>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='login-home.php'>Home</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Now, I did pull this from an [older site](http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/9.html) and kind of 'changed' to suit my own needs to no avail. I even did a complete copy/paste of their Tutorial (inclusive of their Database) and even that did not work, which seems to indicate something is wrong with the code somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What debugging have you done? I think you can break this down into a simpler use case. If you need to post this much code I suspect you can be doing more to troubleshoot this.

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think the record did not update?

Comment: Hm, i don't see where you set $barcode, $product and other variables.

Comment: Hi Dan, not my actual assets.php page as well as the table when checking within phpMyAdmin as well. As below, I believe the error lies with lack of variables, of which im about to test out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in the second script setting those variables.  The form values don't automatically pass into variables, you have to retrieve them from the $_POST array variable, which is why you have that 'post' method in your form on the first page.  You do it like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['barcode']) && $_POST['barcode'] != "") {
    $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
} else {
    echo "'barcode' input is not set.";
}
```

You don't actually need the if statement, but it's nice for troubleshooting and general error prevention.  It just makes sure the field was both set and not empty.

(I would explain arrays, but it seems you already have a grasp on them based on your loop with the $rows variable.  If you need the help there let me know and I'll give a brief explanation and link you out to a tutorial.)

Comment: This is most likely the answer. Just be careful nobody sets `id` to `' OR '1'='1` or worse! (Since you're doing error checking in this code example, someone coming along might think this is complete and try to copy and use it as is!)

Comment: That's fair, although I never claimed it to be complete.  In reality, if you want to get into safety, rather than recommending an amateur to cleanse their data by hand the responsible route would be recommending prepared statements via PDO.  I just didn't bother because the OP is a hobbyist and it sounds like they have no intention of making their script publicly available.

Comment: Agreed 200%. I was mainly commenting for the next person that comes along, sees this question and answer, and moves along without ever knowing there might even be a security issue.

Comment: Fair enough, I really should have taken that into consideration when I made the post.

Comment: That seems correct, after posting this I hunted down a bit more and it seems this may be the case. I'm just about to test and will come back. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work. Using the if statement wouldn't process, so I dumbed it down to be as follows:

Comment: `code'$_POST['barcode']=$barcode;
    $_GET['id']=$id;'code`

And the same for the other entries. I pulled this from this [link](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/58719-php-mysql-update-script.html)

Still being difficult. States success and then has my option to 'view' the original Assets page, but hasn't actually been updated (same with checking the table data in phpMyAdmin). Though I don't see $_POST in update.php only $row that correlates.

Comment: $_POST and $_GET can both be sent through forms, using the 'method' attribute, and $_GET can be sent in a URL (also called a header) like this: www.examplesite.com/page.php?variable=data

Comment: I recommend going to w3schools.com, they have some nice tutorials for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

To update you values you should use $_POST[NAME of SELECT] in you update_ac.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="member2"; // Mysql username 
$password="********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="audits"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="data"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$db_name") or die("cannot connect"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}   

$sql="SELECT * FROM questions";
$result =mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE  SET barcode='$_POST[barcode]' ,product='$_POST[product]' ,category='$_POST[category]' ,assigned='$_POST[assigned]' ,notes='$_POST[notes]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]' ");
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This code will work just copy and paste it in update_ac.php